# Aggregate over foreign key attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-postgresql

I want to know the number of questions that has been asked to a specific user.

Here are my models

```
class TrueOrFalseQuestion(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    explanation = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)

class TrueOrFalseUserQuestion(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(TrueOrFalseQuestion, related_name='user_questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Someone creates a question, then when I want to display it for a specific user, I create a TrueOrFalseUserQuestion (and assign the user as `creator`).

I want to know how many times a question has been displayed to each user. Let's say user with id 1 has 5 TrueOrFalseUserQuestion and user 2 has 3, then I would like to have this result

`{"1": 5, "2": 3}`

It's easy to do with Python but I think it will give poor performance, is there a way to do that using Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = TrueOrFalseUserQuestion.objects.filter(
    question=some_question
).values(
    'creator'
).annotate(
    times=Count('id')
).order_by(
    'creator'
)
```

With `some_question` the question for which we want to obtain counts.

This will result in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, like:

```
<QuerySet [{'creator': 1, 'times': 5}]>
```

We can then use dictionary comprehension, like:

```
result = {
    q['creator'] : q['times'] for q in qs
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped a lot, thank you. The result I wanted (which I might not have explained correctly) was

`qs = TrueOrFalseUserQuestion.objects.filter(creator=user).values('question').annotate(times=Count('id')).order_by('question')`

`result = { q['question'] : q['times'] for q in qs }`

Comment: @FlorianThuin: ah, the transpose: counting per question, instead of per user :) Yeah, indeed, but it is the same reasoning behind it.